# Match between two characters

Tags: ruby, regex

Is this possible?

From this string:

```
string = "lsdfh892pr23hr4342pr3j4r\n\nwww.foobar.com•\nyahoogooglebing"
```

I want to extract `"www.foobar.com"`.

And, from this one:

```
string = "lsdfh892pr23hr4342pr3j4r\n\ninfo@google.com•\nyahoogooglebing"
```

I want to extract `"info@google.com"`.

Comment: What do you want to extract? Strings which match a domain pattern, or strings between new lines?

Comment: string between \n\n and • ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the ruby syntax, but this regex should work:

```
/\n\n([^•]*)•/
```

Comment: That'll do it. In Ruby, you could just `email = string[/\n\n([^•]*)•/,1]` or more simply:  `email = string[/\n\n(.+?)•/,1]`

Comment: @Phrogz I added the /m flag after your regex and it worked perfectly! could you make it an answer? and I will accept it!

Comment: @Phrogz сould you explain, what means `,1` in your example, please.

Comment: @test It's the index of the capture to extract. See [the docs for `String#[]` for details](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with a regular expression:

```
string = "lsdfh892pr23hr4342pr3j4r\n\nwww.foobar.com•\nyahoogooglebing"
string.split("\n")[2][0..-2]
=> "www.foobar.com"

string = "lsdfh892pr23hr4342pr3j4r\n\ninfo@google.com•\nyahoogooglebing"
string.split("\n")[2][0..-2]
=> "info@google.com"
```

Comment: split is a simple kind of regex, and, here, it does not simplify the code, make the extraction less flexible (you don't know if emails or domains are on the third line every time), and does not improve the performance.

Comment: Yes, `split` coerces the string `"\n"` to a regex, but, it relieves the OP of needing to maintain any sort of more complex pattern. It's up to the OP to say whether the string always has the site name on the third line. In this case, it's consistent with the data samples given, and just as safe to assume as it is to assume there's always a "bullet" or two proceeding "\n".

Comment: Ok the regexs can be complex to maintain. Yet, I think that I prefer code with a good semantic. And `split` is not made specifically to extract content.

Comment: yes. the emails/urls will always be on the third line for my case.. this is also a working solution.. however I wanted to learn some regex to understand how this would work in regex. however, your approach also taught me something new! I wish I could mark 2 answers as correct!